# Visualize the data in Memchache cluster in Elasticache

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I am using the memcache cluster in Elasticache. On the AWS UI, I do not see the data I am storing in the cache (storing a JSON response object). Is there a way I can visualize this json?

Why I want to see the data being cached:
I recently updated the json structure that needs to be stored and want to verify that the new structure is being stored in cache.

Answer (score 2):

AWS just manages the Memchached servers for you. It doesn't really concern itself with the data. You would need to connect to the Memcached cluster via a Memcached client to view the data.

Comment: I installed the memcache CLI and used telnet to connect to the cluster and query. Was able to fetch the data I wanted!